# What is the semantic difference between "^(?P<x>\d?)" and "^(?P<x>\d)?"?

Tags: python, regex

I have been working with long regular expressions used to extract information from input strings where some fields are optional and I wonder if there is a practical difference between:

- Describe an optional subexpression containing group names:

> `^(?P<x>\d)?`

- ... and describe an expression containing group names referring to an optional expression:

> `^(?P<x>\d?)`

I know they are not exactly the same expression since the former is an optional expression whereas the later is a non-optional expression containing an optional expression but both expressions give the same result. Is there any difference I am not seeing?  Is any of them more efficient than the other when using python "re" module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me be your terminal:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.match("^(?P<x>\d)?(?P<rest>.)", "abc").groupdict()
{'x': None, 'rest': 'a'}
>>> re.match("^(?P<x>\d?)(?P<rest>.)", "abc").groupdict()
{'x': '', 'rest': 'a'}
>>>
```

In other words, `(\d?)` always succeeds and matches an empty string if there are no digits, while `(\d)?` can fail and return a `None` group.

Comment: I only want to get the values if they match so this difference means I have to check whether the dictionary entry is None in the first case or wether I have to check if the dictionary entry is an empty string. Should I assume is more efficent the first way?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: yes, optional groups should me more efficient, since the engine won't waste time creating empty groups.